# On a columns chart from highcharts, how to set xAxis labels at columns edges?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using a column chart from highcharts. I would like to know how to have a xAxis displayed like that ? (Don't pay attention to the vertical line)

[image: columns image]

I tried to use xAxis with categories but without real success. I also tried to add a point interval but in both cases, labels are displayed under columns at center.

[image: wrong display of columns]

I'm not finding a way on highcharts documentation to have this result.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `pointPlacement` to `between` is a solution which you are looking for.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mnce2r9q/

```
  series: [{
        type: 'column',
        pointPlacement: 'between',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for !